# How call out the value inside the for loop as an array to the outside of the for loop in twig?

Tags: php, twig

I've stuck a calling out the value inside the **for loop** to the outside of the loop as an **array** in **twig template**.
I use the following code

```
{% set delMethod = 0 %} // set the value
// for loop
{%- for deliveryId,tmpship2 in tmpship -%}
{%- set delivery = get_entity_manager().find('EcCoreBundle:Delivery', deliveryId) -%}
{%- set deliveryAbroads = delivery.abroads(country) -%}

{% set delMethod = tmpship2.delivery_abroad %} // contains more than one value.

{%- endfor -%}

{{ delMethod }} // as an array.
```

in the above code, I want to call out the `{{ delMethod }}` as an **array** that contains more than one value.

I really appreciate it if you guys answer me.
Thank you.

Comment: Unclear, if `delMethod` is indeed an array, you can just loop it like, `{% for value in delMethod %}{{ value }}{% endfor %}`. I do have to point out that in your initial `for`-loop you are overwriting `delMethod` each time instead of appending values

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee, I have already changed the code for my result.